# How to launch my Android app from a QR reader?

Tags: android, parameters, launch

I've tried searching for similar questions, but none have been quite clear on this topic.

So, I have an app, and I want to use QR code reader to launch it. For example, if I take a photo of a QR code, the QR reader will translate it into a web address and launch my app with that address as the parameter. How do I do this? I have no access to the QR reader, as it can be any app from the store. How do I make my app to appear in the list of available programs to handle the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to launch my Android app from a QR reader?

You don't, exactly. You allow your Android app to be launched based on particular `Intent` structures, one or more of which might be used by a QR code reader.

> For example, if I take a photo of a QR code, the QR reader will translate it into a web address and launch my app with that address as the parameter. How do I do this?

Have an `<intent-filter>` on your `<activity>` that says that it handles that URL, such as:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data
                android:host="www.this-so-does-not-exist.com"
                android:path="/something"
                android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

That `<intent-filter>` will match the URL `http://www.this-so-does-not-exist.com/something`. Changing the `<data>` element will change what URL(s) you match.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can set your own scheme like this.

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <data
            android:host="something"
            android:scheme="myapp"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

If you put "`myapp://someting/string to send to app`" your app will start and you will get the last part by using the below code

```
getIntent().getData().getLastPathSegment()
```